# Delete RVM Gemset with @ sign in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemset

Somehow, I have a gemset that has an `@` sign in it and I can't figure out how to delete it.

```
MacBook-Pro:project user$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
=> dalli
   dalli@dalli
```

running `rvm gemset delete dalli@dalli` yields `Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): dalli.`

Is there a way to delete this gemset that I bungled?

Comment: extra note - this was a bug for short time, make sure to update rvm: `rvm get head`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per mpapis comment, I updated RVM and the troublesome gemset went away.  Looks like I stumbled onto a bug that had been fixed and I just needed to update RVM.

To update RVM: `rvm get head`

Answer (score 2):

You will have to manually delete it, since you are not supposed to add a gemset containing an `@` sign in the first place. Try to delete the gemset in `.rmv/gems` and `.rvm/gemsets` and do a `grep -r "your@gemset" .` to find all remaining references. .

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cd ~/.rvm/gems
$ rm -r ruby-1.9.3-p392@dalli@dalli
```

you're done ;) You can also rename it and remove with `rvm gemset delete` but as far as I know this does the same as above command, if not, correct me.